# Hide unordered list when losing parent focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field. When user  focuses on that input a unordered list appears beneath that input.

When user clicks on one of the list children that data is inserted into input and unordered list is hidden.

*CURRENT PROBLEM*

If a user clicks on input , but doesn't choose any of the options and then click somewhere else in the document the unordered list will remain shown.

I don't if there's some kind of event I'm missing that I could use to solve this.

```js
$('body').on('focus blur click', '.autocomplete input , .autocomplete ul,  .autocomplete li' , function() {

if (event.type === 'focus' && event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') { 
  $(this).siblings('ul').show();
 } else if ((event.type === 'blur' || event.type === 'click' ) && event.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
  $(this).parent('ul').hide();
 }

});


$('body').on('click' ,'li' ,function() {
 
 $('#P1_FIRST_NAME').val($(this).attr('data-value'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input__container autocomplete">
    <div class="input__label__container">
        <label for="P1_FIRST_NAME" tabindex="999">Autocomplete</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="P1_FIRST_NAME" class="text_field" autocomplete="off" value="">
    <ul for="P1_FIRST_NAME" style="display: none;">
        <li tabindex="1" data-value="MAD">Madder</li>
        <li tabindex="1" data-value="SAD">Sandy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to hide unorder list ? when user clicks on some where in document?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that. I want to hide currently shown unordered list. ( Since there could be more than one on the same page )

Comment: Looks like you want to implement something like autocomplete. Maybe you should look for an existing autocomplete plugin, there are many that work very well.

Comment: @Tomalak Heh yeah I am, but this is the only thing that's missing. ( for now ). I've already managed to get my data from backend so that's solved.

Comment: *"this is the only thing that's missing"* I would bet against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes

- You can use an object with `.on()` to pass in multiple event handlers. Don't use if/else to switch between different behaviors for different events.
- don't hard-code the ID of the element you want to set into your JS code. Use a `data-` attribute (see `targetSelector` below).
- Work with `.closest()` to navigate to the correct elements.
- Use CSS positioning for the `<ul>` so that it does not push down content below.

```js
$('body')
    .on({
        'focus': function() {
            var $ul = $(this).closest('.autocomplete').find('ul');
            $ul.width( $(this).width() ).show();
        },
        'blur': function() {
            var $ul = $(this).closest('.autocomplete').find('ul');
            setTimeout(function () { $ul.fadeOut('fast'); }, 250);
        }
    }, '.autocomplete input')
    .on('click', '.autocomplete li', function() {
        var targetSelector = $(this).closest('ul').data('for');
        $(targetSelector).val( $(this).data('value') );
        $(this).closest('ul').fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

```css
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}
.autocomplete ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.59);
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.autocomplete ul li {
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.autocomplete ul li:hover {
  background-color: #FCF3CF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input__container autocomplete">
    <div class="input__label__container">
        <label for="P1_FIRST_NAME" tabindex="999">Autocomplete</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="P1_FIRST_NAME" class="text_field" autocomplete="off" value="">
    <ul data-for="#P1_FIRST_NAME">
        <li data-value="MAD">Madder</li>
        <li data-value="SAD">Sandy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>content below content below content below content below content below</p>
```

Comment: I wanted to keep css out of this question since I figured it was irrelevant. I have that covered. Thanks for everything else , I learned thing or two!

Answer (score 2):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/4z76r1pn/1/)

you need to bind a click event at `html` and stop event propagation at `input` and `ul` level

```
$('body').on('focus blur click', '.autocomplete input , .autocomplete ul,  .autocomplete li' , function(e) {

if (event.type === 'focus' && event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') { 
  $(this).siblings('ul').show();
 } else if ((event.type === 'blur' || event.type === 'click' ) && event.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
  $(this).parent('ul').hide();
 }
 e.stopPropagation();

});


$('body').on('click' ,'li' ,function(e) {

 $('#P1_FIRST_NAME').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
 e.stopPropagation();

});

$("html").click( function(e) {

 $('ul').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to use "this" selectors if there's more than one on a page, but here's one way to click the field to show the ul list and click away from the ul list to hide it again:

```js
$( ".text_field" ).click(function() {
  $('ul').show();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $("ul");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('ul').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input__container autocomplete">
    <div class="input__label__container">
        <label for="P1_FIRST_NAME" tabindex="999">Autocomplete</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="P1_FIRST_NAME" class="text_field" autocomplete="off" value="">
    <ul for="P1_FIRST_NAME" style="display: none;">
        <li tabindex="1" data-value="MAD">Madder</li>
        <li tabindex="1" data-value="SAD">Sandy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```